# Ingresar a paginaweb usando dominio que apunte a ip pública con puerto determinado

Tags: python, linux, docker, flask, gunicorn

en mi homelab desde mi linux server, intento crear un contenedor (docker) con la pag web en python con flask sirviendo desde gunicorn que apunte hacia mi ip publica.
Ejemplo:

- Ip linux serv 192.168.1.100 -hecho.
- Puerto designado para la página web: 5000 - hecho. (configurado en ufw, contenedor, gunicorn y router de ethernet)
- ejemplo de acceso, ip publica. 189.150.150.1:5000 - hecho. puedo acceder sin problema a mi página web desde fuera de mi red lan.
- acceder a la pagina web desde un dominio (en google domains) [www.webpage.com](http://www.webpage.com) - hecho.  Para esto, lo que hice fue forwardear en mi proveedor de dominio hacia mi ip publica con el puerto 5000. Funciona todo ok.

El problema es que al teclear [www.webpage.com](http://www.webpage.com) y al entrar en la página web no me muestra mi dominio, sino que me muestra mi ippublica:5000 y quiero que se mantenga el nombre del dominio que estoy usando.

Es cuestión de configurarle algo en el proveedor de dominio o en el linux server?

Al final lo que deseo poder aprender es a como servir, desde mi homelab,  varias páginas web desde una sola ip publica pero desde distintos puertos. Quizas y esta no sea la forma de hacerlo, me podrían indicar si es la mas óptima para hacerlo desde mi red de casa?

He intentado usar ngnix pero es mas avanzado y me pierdo mucho con el dockercompose.

El ddns lo tengo resuelto con un cron 24/7 que vaya y actualice la ip publica de mi proveedor de dominio cuando esta cambie.

Comment: El dominio debe apuntar a la ip, sin el puerto. Ya luego al acceder desde el navegador se agrega el puerto al final.

Comment: hola @Lobos, entiendo la solución que comentas, pero es la mas optima para servir varias pagians web desde la misma ip?

el ejemplo de lo que me dices seria algo asi?
www.webpage.com:5000 ?? si es así no es lo que estoy buscando, busco que sea transparente para el usuario y que solo digite www.webpage.com y que de forma transparente se redirija a :5000

Comment: La siguiente opción es un proxy inverso con nginx, no estan complicado de implementar y así podrías tener www.webpage.com/servicio1, www.webpage.com/servicio2 etc... Eso sí, cada dominio debe tener un diferenciador para que sepa a que puerto debe redirigir el tráfico. Puedes probar ngrok también https://ngrok.com/